# Zend 2 Dynamic Content in Layout with View Helpers

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new in Zend FW 2 and I try to showing data from database in layout but I receive error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\View\Helper\HotNews::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\webtruonghoc\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 207 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\webtruonghoc\module\Application\src\Application\View\Helper\HotNews.php on li
```

Function getViewHelperConfig in Module.php:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
            'factories' => array(
                    'hotNews' => function($sm) {
                        $adapter = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Model\NewsTable');
                        return new HotNews($adapter);
                    },
            ),
    );
}
```

Add code in module.config.php:

```
    'view_helpers' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
                    'hotnews' => 'Application\View\Helper\HotNews',
            ),
```

File HotNews.php:

```
 <?php


namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

class HotNews extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $adapter;

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM news order by date DESC limit 0,4";
        return $resultSet = $this->adapter->query($sql, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    }
}
```

and final I showing data in layout:

```
<?php  $hotnews = $this->hotNews(); 
                            var_dump($hotnews);
                    ?>
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting your model to be set up as a service. but may not have set up the service correctly. In your module.config.php file, there should be an entry under 'service_manager' => 'factories' :

```
return array(        
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Application\Model\NewsTable' => function (ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
              //... returns an instance of Application\Model\NewsTable
            }
        )
    )
);
```

Your SQL has an error in it. Also, you should not be executing SQL statements inside a view helper, and passing the entire result set of a select * to the view is bad JuJu as well. I would place the SQL inside a Repository class which returns DTO objects representing your data model. You could then inject the repository into your ViewHelper and and use those DTOs in your view.

Comment: I use function getServiceConfig() in Module.php:
return array(
       'factories' => array(
         'Application\Model\NewsTable' =>  function($sm) {
          $tableGateway = $sm->get('NewsTableGateway');
          $table = new NewsTable($tableGateway);
          return $table;
         },

Is that right?